# Ether is not reflecting in my Metamask account

Tags: metamask, etherscan

My friend has transferred me some ether to my Metamask account but the ether hasn't reflected in my wallet. But in the ether scan, it is showing that my transaction was successful. What can I do to resolve this issue?
Txn Hash: 0x03eafde3fc15f385f9839857ca664d5c46d35a2b935e00c6013500e5bae82d84

Comment: The recipient of that transaction has immediate send the value to another address (within 3 blocks).

Answer (score 0):

Metamask sometimes has issues updating, I think it's due to Infura being overcapacity. The long term option is to run your own node, but a quick fix is to open metamask and change your network away from mainnet and back. That'll usually force a refresh of your balances.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the extension to only work in certain sites, but changing the option to **On all sites**, that might work.